# Trying to Authenticate to an API using Python and Store Access Token

Tags: python, json, api, authentication

I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "authenticate-smartling.py", line 20, in 
api_response.json()['response']['data']['accessToken']
KeyError: 'data'

```
import sys
import os
import requests
import json

# Read authentication credentials from environment
user_id = os.environ.get('DEV_USER_IDENTIFIER')
user_secret = os.environ.get('DEV_USER_SECRET')
project_id = os.environ.get('DEV_PROJECT_ID')

# Authenticate
api_url = 'https://api.smartling.com/auth-api/v2/authenticate'
api_parameters = {
    'userIdentifier': user_id,
    'userSecret': user_secret
}
api_response = requests.post(api_url, json = api_parameters)
        
# Store access token for use in subsequent API calls    
api_response.json()['response']['data']['accessToken']
```

Comment: try printing `api_response.json()['response']` for available keys

Comment: @deadshot I replaced the last line with print(api_response.json()['response']) and received the following error: {'code': 'AUTHENTICATION_ERROR', 'errors': [{'key': 'unauthorized', 'message': 'Unauthorized', 'details': None}]}
PS D:\.projects\smartling>

Comment: you haven't completed the authentication, response You are getting is error response, try checking your credentials, also use `api_response.raise_for_status()`, it will throw an exception if the request is not succeeded